# Host my own picture web site and have links for people to order photos through other services

Tags: images, photo-gallery, photo

I have too many pictures and I don't want to pay for storage with Picasa or a similar site as I have my own hosting space that I pay for already.

Is there any way I can keep my own hosted pictures and website but still allow people to click to order pictures through other services?

Comment: Specifically, what other services?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used these but here are some possibilities...

http://www.cmsaccount.com/  - "Prints and shipped products"

http://www.ktools.net/

http://www.xpoze.org/

http://www.lightboxphoto.com/

http://gallery.menalto.com/

And here's a list of photo gallery software on Wikipedia...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_photo_gallery_software

Answer (score 2):

Most picture sales sites I have encountered DO require that you host your images with them.

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you could implement your own shopping cart (pick one of the many available) to allow others to order photos through your own site.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the [Gallery Project](http://galleryproject.org/) which is an open source photo-gallery with shopping cart, although never the shopping cart features. It is highly extensible and numerous plugins (including many that expand the shopping cart features) are freely available. The one downside is that it requires PHP and MySQL (and you have specified ASP.NET). However, both PHP and MySQL can run in IIS and whatever server you are using may already have them setup.

> Sadly, [Gallery is now in hibernation](http://galleryproject.org/time-to-hibernate) until further notice.
>
> The Gallery team has decided to take a step back from actively
>   maintaining this project. Truth be told, most of the core team got
>   busy with their lives over the past few years and we haven't had the
>   time to really actively maintain the project in a long time. The
>   forums have continued to be lively and helpful and there is still
>   plenty of good conversation there - but no new code has been written
>   in the past 6 months and that's not likely to change.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use some open source e-commerce application for this.You can setup your pictures as products and people can buy it.**oscommerce** is a good choice to start if you know little bit PHP. It has got wide range of add-ons which u can use to integrate the payment option and all.

**OSCOMMERCE Link**
 http://www.oscommerce.com/solutions/downloads

Reasons you should consider such products

1) Already tested by many people

2) You can save lot of time.just download the source code and modify it as per your requirements.

3) Wide range of addons and community support